Proof of $V_F(-\infty,b]=\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]$ where $F$ is of finite variation.
I am reading the proof of the following result:

Proposition$\quad$ Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation. If $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]=\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b].
$$

The proof goes as follows:

Proof$\quad$ Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number, choose an increasing sequence $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ of numbers that belong to $(-\infty,b]$ and satisfy
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon,
$$
and note that for each $a$ that satisfies $a\leq t_0$ we have
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon<V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b].
$$

I am confused by the proof. I don't think the argument is sufficient to prove the proposition. I wanted to use the squeeze theorem but I don't think I will work, because it doesn't satisfy the conditions in the squeeze theorem. Could someone please help me explain why the proof works? Thanks a lot in advance!


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes the interval $[a,b]$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    a \leq t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq b.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F[a,b]$, the variation of $F$ over $[a,b]$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F[a,b] = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) on $[a,b]$ if $V_F[a,b]$ is finite.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes the interval $(-\infty,b]$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq b.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F(-\infty,b]$, the variation of $F$ over $(-\infty,b]$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F(-\infty,b] = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^{n}\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) on $(-\infty,b]$ if $V_F(-\infty,b]$ is finite.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n < +\infty.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F(-\infty,+\infty)$, the variation of $F$ over $\mathbb{R}$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F(-\infty,+\infty) = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{t=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) if $V_F(-\infty,+\infty)$ is finite. If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation, then the variation of $F$ is the function $V_F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $V_F(x)=V_F(-\infty,x]$.


Sure. I will follow the statement of squeeze theorem from wikipedia. Since the $\epsilon$ is chosen beforehand, $\lim_{a\to-\infty}(V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon)\neq\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F(-\infty,b]$, and so it does not satisfy the conditions in the squeeze theorem.

@MartinR Could you please elaborate the full definition of $\lim_{a\to-\infty}$? I just realized that I have never seen formal definitions of infinite limit and limit at infinity.  Thank you very much!

Perhaps it would be clarifying if the questioner could say what sense they mean for a "limit" of (topological?) vector spaces of functions. Looks like a "colimit" to me, which might render some questions irrelevant... Clarify?

@paulgarrett Thanks for your comment. The "limit" is in the most commonly understood sense in real analysis, as in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit of a function. I just have never encountered, and have never realized that this would be a problem, that how I should formally deal with "infinite limit" and "limit at infinity".

The squeeze theorem is not needed here, just the definition of $\lim_{a \to -\infty}$.
To simplify the notation, set $f(t) = V_F([t, b])$ and $L = V_F(-\infty,b]$.
In the quoted proof it has been shown that

For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $t_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $L - \epsilon < f(a) \le L $ for all $a \le t_0$.

It follows that

For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $t_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $|f(a)-L| < \epsilon $ for all $a \le t_0$.

and that is exactly the definition of $\lim_{a \to -\infty} f(t) = L$, see for example $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for limits involving $\infty$ .

I would rewrite the proof as follows:

Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number. Choose a finite increasing sequence $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ of numbers that belong to $(-\infty,b]$ and satisfy
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon.
$$
Note that for each $a$ that satisfies $a\leq t_0$, we have $V_F[a,b]\geq\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon$, and so $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]>V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]\geq V_F(-\infty,b]$; for otherwise, we can pick $\epsilon=V_F(-\infty,b]-\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]>0$ to obtain $V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon=\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]$, a contradiction. Moreover, $V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b]$ for any $a\leq b$, so $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b]$. Hence, $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]=V_F(-\infty,b]$.

Now there is a subtlety here: we need to prove that the limit $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]$ exists. This can be done as follows:

First note that for any $a_1\leq a_2\leq b$ we have $V_F[a_1,b]\geq V_F[a_2,b]$. Thus as $a\to-\infty$, $V_F[a,b]\to\lambda\in[0,+\infty]$. Suppose that $\lambda=+\infty$. Then as $a\to-\infty$, $V_F[a,b]\to+\infty$. Note that for all $a\leq b$, $V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b]$. We now show that, as $a\to-\infty$, $V_F[a,b]\to+\infty\leq V_F(-\infty,b]$. Assume to the contrary that $V_F(-\infty,b]<+\infty$. $V_F[a,b]\to+\infty$ as $a\to-\infty$ means that for every neghborhood $U$ of $+\infty$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $-\infty$ such that $V\bigcap\mathbb{R}\neq\emptyset$, and such that $V_F[a,b]\in U$ for all $a\in V\bigcap\mathbb{R}$, $a\neq-\infty$. Let $U=(V_F(-\infty,b]+1,+\infty)$, then we can fnd an interval $(-\infty,c)$ such that $V_F[a,b]>V_F(-\infty,b]+1$ for all $a\in(-\infty,c)$, so that if we let $a=\min\{b,c\}-1$ then we will obtain $V_F(-\infty,b]<V_F[a,b]-1<V_F[a,b]$, contradicting the fact that $V_F(-\infty,b]\geq V_F[a,b]$ for all $a\leq b$. Therefore, $V_F(-\infty,b]\geq+\infty$. But this is impossible because $F$ is of finite variation implies $V_F(-\infty,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,+\infty)<+\infty$. Hence, as $a\to-\infty$, $V_F[a,b]\to\lambda\in[0,+\infty)$; that is, the limit $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]$ exists.


It has been shown that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $t_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon<V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b]$ for all $a \le t_0$. That already proves that $\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]$ exists, and is equal to $V_F(-\infty,b]$. There is no subtlety here and no need to prove the existence of the limit separately.

@MartinR Do you mean "For all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon<V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b]$ for all $a\leq t_0$ (and so for all $a<t_0$)" implies "For every interval $\left(V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon,V_F(-\infty,b]\right]$ (and thus for every neighborhood $U=\left(V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon,V_F(-\infty,b]+\epsilon\right)$ of $V_F(-\infty,b]$) there is a neighborhood $V=(-\infty,t_0)$ of $-\infty$" such that $V_F[a,b]\in\left(V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon,V_F(-\infty,b]\right]$ (and thus $V_F[a,b]\in U$) for all $a\in V=(-\infty,t_0)$, which proves the equality?

Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

@MartinR Thank you so much! Yeah, my answer is indeed unnecessary. My bad.

For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\epsilon_m=\frac{1}{m}$ and choose an increasing finite sequence $\{t_i^m\}_{i=0}^{n_m}$ of numbers that belong to $(-\infty,b]$ and satisfy
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n_m}|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon_m,
$$
and note that for each $a$ that satisfies $a\leq t_0^m$ we have
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon_m<V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b].
$$
So for all $a$ that satisfies $a\leq\min\{t_0^1,t_0^2,\dots,t_0^m\}\leq t_0^m$ we must have
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon_m<V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b].
$$
Now consider the sequence $\{t_0^m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$. If it is bounded below by $K$, then for any $a\leq K$ we have
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon_m<V_F[a,b]\leq V_F(-\infty,b].
$$
Since $m\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary, it follows that $V_F[a,b]=V_F(-\infty,b]$. Now if $\{t_0^m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is not bounded below, that is, $\inf\{t_0^1,t_0^2,\dots\}=-\infty$, then there is a subsequence $\{t_0^{m^k}\}$ of $\{t_0^m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ such that $t_0^{m_k}\to-\infty$. So for any $a\leq\min\{t_0^1,\dots,t_0^{m_k}\}=t_0^{m_k}$ (without loss of generality, assume $\{t_0^{m_k}\}$ is decreasing) we have
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon_{m_k} < V_F[a,b] \leq V_F(-\infty,b].
$$
Fix any $\epsilon>0$. There exists an $m_k$ such that $\epsilon_{m_k}<\epsilon$ and that $a\leq t_0^{m_k}$ implies
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon < V_F(-\infty,b]-\epsilon_{m_k} < V_F[a,b] \leq V_F(-\infty,b],
$$
that is,
$$
V_F(-\infty,b]-V_F[a,b]<\epsilon.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{a\to-\infty}V_F[a,b]=V_F(-\infty,b].
$$
